# sudden change in port number of closest relay when changed to pasing traffic of Firefox through Tor network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, configuration, directory

I understand to obtain the complete successful results out of Tor, is it mandatory to use Tor browser bundle. But sometimes, for a general user, Firefox is much tempting to use for many reasons as a daily driver and TorBB when complete anonymity id required.

I have been monitoring my traffic and I’ve noticed some changes when TBB runs and when Tor is used with Proxychains + Iceweasel(firefox).(Note:the entry point may change every 2 weeks approx, comments welcome as to **why**)

When TBB is running the entry point relay always has port: 9001. (the ip changes but it is always on the same port) But when some other application uses TOR network the entry point relay is different from the TBB's. It tries to establish connection on the same ip but a different port.

Usually Proxychains(also privoxy) or firefoxs' TCP/IP packets connect to relay whose port is 443.

**Question 0:**

I´ve checked and both are trusted entry points(relays) but why are the ports different?

**Question 1:** 
What causes this change?

**Question 2:**
How to stop this change?

**Question 3:**

Does this mean that packets generated through Tor browser are differently encrypted?

Comment: Actually the only question that does not have an obvious explanation is nº 0

Comment: If connect to port 443, makes difficult to identify that you are using Tor, is also for ppl behind a firewall, there is no need to stop it, same encryption.

Comment: yes it makes a lot sense. thank you. But, then why cant we route the Tor traffic the same way? What stops the developers from routing othe usual Tor traffic too through 443? ?  Im a little curious to know

Comment: It is not a purpose to hide that someone is using Tor (at least not in the "western world", it's legal) besides this is a well-known port for HTTPS imagine that someone who is
running a relay wants also to run some other service through the same port, i remember years ago skype used a well-know port for something by default it was a mess to configure an apache server
,but is useful because of the reasons that i said above.
btw maybe you should edit your question or close it, if i find out why does it Tor i'll tell you.

Comment: thank you for the information. yes, it sounds like it. But still, my questions stand. what is the purpose of having two distinct ports?
Could you please advice me as to why my question may need to be closed? I cannot understand a reason.

Comment: Every relay has just one entry point, it could be 9001 or 443 but one. About your questions number 2,3,0 are already answered on the comments the point is why when Tor and TBB are installed on the same linux distribution both do not connect to the same entry point ? i've a partial answer for this but is not proven yet, both processes are Tor and also independent. One thing is for sure, it does not have any security problem, issue, bug to worry about.

Comment: This question is overly vague, you describe multiple changes (the guards, the ports, the ips) and never clarify which you mean in your "questions". You do not make clear what your setup is and how you've configured tor browser which might explain the behaviour you are seeing.